# Render an array with a different view in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, jsx

I have an array of logs that have the following structure let's say:

```
LogItems = [
    {
       description: "I am the first log";
       timestamp: "2023-02-20T20:15:43.2357511Z"
    }, 
    {
       description: "I am the fourth log";
       timestamp: "2023-02-20T21:20:43.2357511Z"
    }, 
    {
       description: "I am the second log";
       timestamp: "2023-01-20T20:10:43.2357511Z"
    },
    {
       description: "I am the third log";
       timestamp: "2023-01-20T20:10:43.2357511Z"
    }
];
```

Now, I want to render this data in a different react component.
I want to show this list as described below:

```
20 Jan 2023
    8:10:PM
         I am the second log
         I am the third log
20 Feb 2023
   8:15 PM
        I am the first log
   9:20 PM
        I am the fourth log
```

Should I create a new object literal from the logs array to create a nested array similar to the view I create or can I directly render this data in JSX in the desired view?
I am new to react so, any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: you can group by date then time. after that iterate and render

Comment: @cmgchess Can you please show it to me as an example code since, I am new to this

Comment: do you use some library for date manipulations

Comment: @cmgchess No and I would prefer not to add any dependencies

Comment: your question actually covers content worth 3 questions if you also consider formatting part and react part

Answer (score 2):

you can use `reduce` to group the array into an object grouped by date and time. I have used 2 helper functions to format the date and time. Since you need January first I first sorted the array by epoch

```js
const LogItems = [   {       description: "I am the first log",       timestamp: "2023-02-20T20:15:43.2357511Z"    },     {       description: "I am the fourth log",       timestamp: "2023-02-20T21:20:43.2357511Z"    },    {       description: "I am the second log",      timestamp: "2023-01-20T20:10:43.2357511Z"    },    {       description: "I am the third log",       timestamp: "2023-01-20T20:10:43.2357511Z"    }];

// Format date
const formattedDate = (date) => `${date.getUTCDate()} ${date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short',timeZone: 'UTC' })} ${date.getUTCFullYear()}`

// Format time
const formattedTime = (date) => `${date.getUTCHours() % 12 || 12}:${date.getUTCMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : ''}${date.getUTCMinutes()} ${date.getUTCHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`


const res = LogItems
.map(x => ({...x,timestamp:new Date(x.timestamp)}))
.sort((a,b) => a.timestamp.getTime()-b.timestamp.getTime())
.reduce((acc,{description, timestamp})=>{
  const fDate = formattedDate(timestamp)
  const fTime = formattedTime(timestamp)
  acc[fDate] = acc[fDate] || {}
  acc[fDate][fTime] = acc[fDate][fTime] || []
  acc[fDate][fTime].push(description)
  return acc
},{})
console.log(res)
```

In react you can use nested map calls to do the nested rendering of the object. `Object.entries` is used to convert the object to an array of `[key,value]` pairs so that I can call `map` on it. Also use a unique value for the `key` prop and refrain from using array `index`. Just used for simplicity here

```js
const res = {
  "20 Jan 2023": {
    "8:10 PM": [
      "I am the second log",
      "I am the third log"
    ]
  },
  "20 Feb 2023": {
    "8:15 PM": [
      "I am the first log"
    ],
    "9:20 PM": [
      "I am the fourth log"
    ]
  }
}


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(res).map(([date, times]) => (
        <div key={date}>
          <h2>{date}</h2>
          {Object.entries(times).map(([time, logs]) => (
            <div key={time}>
              <h3>{time}</h3>
              <ul>
                {logs.map((log, index) => (
                  <li key={index}>{log}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='app'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should group your logs by day, the format shoud be like this `2023-01-20` .
Then group your logs by time, the format should be like this `20:10`.

Your final array should be something like this:

```js
LogItems = [
   {
      day: "2023-01-20",
      times: [
         {
            time: "20:10",
            descriptions: [
               "I am the third log",
               "I am the second log"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      day: "2023-02-20",
      times: [
         {
            time: "20:15",
            descriptions: [
               "I am the first log"
            ]
         },
         {
            time: "21:20",
            descriptions: [
               "I am the fourth log"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];
```

This is the code:

```js
  const groupedLogs = LogItems.reduce((result, log) => {
  const [date, time] = log.timestamp.split('T');
  const day = date;
  const hour = time.slice(0, 5);
  const description = log.description;

  const existingDay = result.find((item) => item.day === day);
  if (existingDay) {
    const existingHour = existingDay.times.find((item) => item.time === hour);
    if (existingHour) {
      existingHour.descriptions.push(description);
    } else {
      existingDay.times.push({
        time: hour,
        descriptions: [description],
      });
    }
  } else {
    result.push({
      day: day,
      times: [
        {
          time: hour,
          descriptions: [description],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
  return result;
}, []);
```